# Trying to understand JSON better: Load/Dump vs Encoder/Decoder, how are they different?

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

So looking through the similar questions section there seems to be a lot of similar questions but none that are helpful in understanding what I need to understand or I'm just generally not getting what they are putting down. I'm studying python and up to the JSON part of it however as I do understand most of it loading, dumping, etc. I am having issues understanding the proper encoding/decoding part of it "json.encoder", etc.

Reading over the python documents, the information there is a little hard for me to understand therefore I can't write my own notes on it. Every site or video I've seen doesn't explain the terms json.encoder and json.decoder but simply just go over loads and dumps.

I have understood everything else till this point, but can't continue till I fully understand it so any help is greatly appreciated.

So my question is:
What are the differences exactly between encoding/decoding using loads/dumps and encoder/decoder?

Comment: `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` are classes that actually implement the conversions to/from JSON format.  `dumps()`/`loads()` are convenience functions that create an instance of one of these classes for you, and use it.  You'd normally use the functions - you'd only need to interact with the classes yourself if you needed to customize the behavior in some way that the functions cannot handle.

Comment: I can actually understand that, thank you!